# Which is the most memory optimised layout in Android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have no clue if something like this exists in the first place. This was the question asked in an interview. Can some one throw light which is the most memory optimized layout in Android? As far as I know optimization it depends on how we design the Layout. Any specific answer to this question?

Comment: `Relative Layout` as it uses the Relative amount of space to design.

Comment: You are right.. it depends on your requirement.. For example if you need to show row/ columns this is most optimized by TableLayout not RelativeLayout. Althought there are many who wish RelativeLayout the answer from your side.

Comment: The most memory efficient layout is the one which doesn't contain subviews. The second place is reserved for layouts which only contain views that matter (flat structure), class doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which is the most memory optimized layout in Android?

=> I would say NO layout is memory optimized until its managed and designed with good hierarchy.

Now For taking decision of Which layout to use while preparing UI, it always depends on some points and criteria like:

1. How you design your UI with particular layout (RelativeLayout, TableLayout, GridLayout or any)
2. Hierarchy level you maintain while designing your UI.
3. What types of screen design requirement you have. If you have requirement like Equal length buttons then you should use LinearLayout, have requirement like Tabular display then use TableLayout, etc.

Still, I would suggest you to read [**Optimizing Your UI**](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) or watch video of [HierarchyViewer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAgE7saQUUY&feature=player_embedded) and then check whether you have designed optimized UI or not.

Answer (score 3):

IMO this question is incomplete. One layout may be efficient or inefficient in different conditions and requirements. For example, creating a table with linear layouts is inefficient idea, and creating a single button with table layout is equally inefficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Relative Layout. Because it can eliminate nested view groups and keep your layout hierarchy flat, which improves performance and memory efficiency.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you, but can you provide some references for your claims? I know that you [copy-pasted from Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), but I am really interested if anyone actually measured the performance.

Comment: Nice one... what if you have to design a screen for tabular data (a simple example). does your fav RelativeLayout improve the performance?

Comment: Its not me, our beloved Android founders say so.

Comment: @adrianp: whats wrong if copy paste something which could be informative? Its called sharing ;)

Comment: Can you share the link please?

Comment: @BasimSherif I don't say it's wrong,but I find the information somewhat incomplete (om the Android Developer website).